# WPML language switcher for custom rewrite rules

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, multi-language, plugin-wpml

I am making custom rewrite rules for categories in a dual-language project (german as main, english as second language). The urls look like this

`example.com/fliegen` > shows archive.php for category `fliegen`

`example.com/en/aviation` > shows archive.php for category `aviation` (the translated `fliegen`)

This could be achieved by changing the category-base to `.` (although it doesn't seem to work in my case?)

Unfortunately that wouldn't be enough for me, anyways; there is a custom taxonomy called `filter` in the game aswell, which requires urls like this:

`example.com/fliegen/filter/some-filter`

`example.com/en/aviation/filter/some-filter-translated`

When the project was still single-language, I went that route:

```
add_filter("rewrite_rules_array", function($rules) {
    $newRules = array();

    $cats = get_terms("category", array("hide_empty" => false));

    foreach ($cats as $id => $cat) {
        $slug = $cat->slug;
        $newRules[$slug . "/?$"] = "index.php?category_name=" . $slug;
        $newRules[$slug . "/filter/(.+?)/?$"] = 'index.php?category_name=' . $slug . '&filter=$matches[1]';
    }

    return $newRules;
});
```

This code now also includes the translated category-terms, but obviously doesn't care about the needed `/en/` in the rewrite-rule; **So I now need a way to ask inside the `foreach` loop what language the current term represents.**

Hoooow can I do that?

.

.

PS: If anybody knows where to find proper Docs for all the `icl_`-php functions, that seem to come with WPML, please let me know!

.

## Edit

I found a solution to this myself.

The key is a filter-hook called `wpml_element_language_details`. But WPML changes core functions like `get_terms` so one gets only the terms for the current language. This may be very convenient in most cases, creating rewrite rules based on the currently active language in the backend? Not a good idea... therefore you have to temporarily remove the wpml-filters. Which filters to remove? No idea, .. found that online.

```
add_filter("rewrite_rules_array", function($rules) {
    $newRules = array();

    // remove WPML term filters
    global $sitepress;
    remove_filter('get_term', array($sitepress,'get_term_adjust_id'));
    remove_filter('get_terms_args', array($sitepress, 'get_terms_args_filter'));
    remove_filter('terms_clauses', array($sitepress,'terms_clauses'));
     
    // now get ALL categories of ALL languages,
    $cats = get_terms("category", array("hide_empty" => false)); 
     
    // restore WPML term filters
    add_filter('get_term', array($sitepress,'get_term_adjust_id'));
    add_filter('get_terms_args', array($sitepress, 'get_terms_args_filter'));
    add_filter('terms_clauses', array($sitepress,'terms_clauses'));

    // Loop through the $cats
    foreach ($cats as $id => $cat) {

        $details = apply_filters("wpml_element_language_details", null, array("element_id" => $cat->term_id, "element_type" => "category"));

        $slug = $cat->slug;

        // if necessary, add language prefix
        // not having a source_language_code means this is part of the main language and (in our case) therefore doesn't need a prefix at all
        // (!) this may be different for your WPML installation!
        $lang_prefix = ($details->source_language_code != NULL) 
            ? $details->language_code . "/"
            : ""
        ;

        $newRules[$lang_prefix . $slug . "/?$"] = "index.php?category_name=" . $slug;
        $newRules[$lang_prefix . $slug . "/filter/(.+?)/?$"] = 'index.php?category_name=' . $slug . '&filter=$matches[1]';
    }
```

.

## Language switcher

So far my language switcher looks like this,

```
$lang_switcher = icl_get_languages("skip_missing=0");

foreach ($lang_switcher as $lang) {
    $activeClass = (($lang["active"])) ? " active" : "";
    echo '
        <a href="' . $lang["url"] . '" class="'.$activeClass.'">'. $lang["native_name"] .'</a>
    ';
}
```

I have more special cases, like filterable search-page, filterable author-pages.

How can I now link these different custom urls to each other properly?

Answer (score 0):

A more simple solution for generating the rewrite rules would be to temporarily disable the WPML plugin. I did this using WP-CLI as follows:

```
wp plugin deactivate sitepress-multilingual-cms
wp rewrite flush
wp plugin activate sitepress-multilingual-cms
```

Note that this only works a single time. Each time you add/modify a category, the rewrite list is flushed and only the current language categories show up there. So this is only a solution when your categories do not change, or not often.

Comment: wp-cli is not an option for me